# Perl script to traverse XML tags and list all the tags having dot in it

Tags: regex, xml, perl

I need to print XML tags having dots in it.
Example: bg.tres, resume.pr
Below is the code I tried, but it stopped after first match. I am trying to first extract the tags and then identify tags having dot in it.

```
my $xml = q~<?xml version='1.0'?>
<bg.tres>
 <resume.key='267298871' score='5'>
  <xpath path='xpath://resume'>
   <resume.pr canonversion='2' dateversion='2' present='734060'>
   </resume.pr>
  </xpath>
 </resume>
</bg.tres>~;

 #print $xml,$/;
 foreach $line($xml)
 {
    if($line =~ m/<(.*?)>/)
    {
        print "$1\n";
    }
}
```

Can anyone please review, as all the examples are present with usage of packages and modules, but I need to perform it with simple logic, without functions. No such examples are present, please suggest.

Comment: use an XML parser

Comment: That doesn't look like wellformed XML? Have you considered using wellformed XML and a XML parser instead?

Comment: Two problems: a) that's not XML. b) if it was XML, parsing it with regular expressions is non trivial, because XML is contextual, and regular expressions aren't. c) There are modules that are XML parsers. You should use one.

Answer (score 3):

There's a couple of problems with your request:

1. That's not XML. If that really is your source XML, I suggest you go and hit whoever gave it to you with a rolled up copy of the XML spec. Because malformed XML is *supposed to be fatal*.
2. XML is contextual. Regular expressions are not. Parsing XML with regular expressions is therefore incredibly complicated (it's not *quite* impossible, but it's hard).
3. `xpath` is the XML equivalent of regular expressions. Sort of. It's contextual, and lets you select and match based on XML structure, differentiating between content, tags and attributes.
4. Parsers make the job easy. Use a parser.
5. You're inserting your text into an array `@xml` but it's a single value. So don't, use a scalar. `foreach @xml` isn't doing what you think it's doing, as there's only one element in `@xml`.

So with that in mind - and fixing your XML as little as is needed to *make* it valid XML:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl;
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;

my $src = q~<?xml version='1.0'?>
<bg.tres>
 <resume.key key='267298871' score='5'>
  <xpath path='xpath://resume'>
   <resume.pr canonversion='2' dateversion='2' present='734060'>
   </resume.pr>
  </xpath>
 </resume.key>
</bg.tres>~;

my $xml = XML::Twig -> parse ( $src ); 

foreach my $node ( $xml -> get_xpath ('//*') ) {
   print $node -> tag,"\n" if $node -> tag =~ m/\./;
}
```

Comment: Actual requirement is like, I have a XML file and have to list all the tags having (.) dot in it, without use of parser or any XML in build function. So I tried doing it through regular expressions. But as you have mentioned that its incredibly complicated, can you suggest any simple logic, like use of string function or anything else, not parser.

Comment: No. There is no 'simple logic' because XML _isn't that simple_. Not using a parser for a thing that needs a parser, means you need to write a parser yourself. So ... maybe go have a look at the source code for XML::Twig? (Hint: It's pretty complicated too)

Comment: You're saying there is a requirement to process XML without an XML parser? That's a bit like a requirement to tighten nuts without a spanner. A requirement to do something with the wrong tools is a requirement you should walk away from.

Comment: I tend to use the analogy of 'putting in screws with a hammer'. I mean, you technically can. But the result is messy and unreliable, and screwdrivers aren't all that hard to acquire.

Answer (score -1):

In @xml, you have have only one line, so your regex cannot works.

You need to split your string.

rename @xml in $xml, then

```
my @xml = split(/\n/,$xml);
```

and

```
if ($line =~ m/<([^>]+(?=\.)[^>]+)>/)
```

This code works for me:

```
my $xml = q~<?xml version='1.0'?>
<bg.tres>
 <resume.key='267298871' score='5'>
  <xpath path='xpath://resume'>
   <resume.pr canonversion='2' dateversion='2' present='734060'>
   </resume.pr>
  </xpath>
 </resume>
</bg.tres>~;


 #print $xml,$/;
my @xml = split(/\n/,$xml);

 foreach $line(@xml)
 {
    if($line =~ m/<([^>]+(?=\.)[^>]+)>/)
    {
        print "$1\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Its working now, but regex if($line =~ m/<(.*?)>/) working more accurately than  if($line =~ m/<([^>]+(?=\.)[^>]+)>/) as Tag xpath is missing from the output for this. Thanks :)

Comment: Interesting!  With your regex, I got:  ?xml version='1.0'?
bg.tres
resume.key='267298871' score='5'
xpath path='xpath://resume'
resume.pr canonversion='2' dateversion='2' present='734060'
/resume.pr
/xpath
/resume
/bg.tres
which doesn't match with your request "XML tags having dots".